# wordpress: remove plugin submenu item for specific user

Tags: php, wordpress, backend

On the backend of a WordPress site, the admin menu looks like this:

Dashboard
Media
Pages
Pluginname
–– Edit
–– Short Code
–– Settings
–– FAQs

I would like to hide *Pluginname/Settings* from one admin. Since hovering over *Pluginname/Settings* shows *https://url.xy/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=pluginname&page=plg_settings* , i added these lines of code to the functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );
    function my_remove_menu_pages() {
        global $user_ID;
        if ( $user_ID == 2 ) {
            remove_menu_page( 'pluginname.php' , 'plg_settings.php' );
        }
    }
```

But this does not do anything.
Does anybody have advice for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the hint from speshock I could find the solution. I had to use *remove_submenu_page* instead of *remove_menu_page*:

```
remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=pluginname' , 'plg_settings' );
```

Answer (score 0):

If your not looking at functions code I really recommend just using the admin menu editor. https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/ It will allow you to change the name of the links, the icons, the permissions and so many more options. Hope that it works out for you